# Make zsh tab autocomplete cycle by modification date

Tags: terminal, zsh

Currently when I do `cd D`+ <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> zsh cycles over the all files starting with 'D' in alphabetical order but I want it to instead cycle by reverse modification date. So to show me the most recent file first and go backwards as I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

How can I get my terminal to behave this way?

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:cd:*' file-sort modification
```

This will change the order of file completions for the `cd` command only. Completions for any other program will still be in lexical order. If you want to extend this ordering to specific other programs, for example `cat` and `vim`, you can do so by adding the following instead:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:(cd|cat|vim):*' file-sort modification
```

And if  you want to use this ordering for all filename completions, the following will do the trick:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' file-sort modification
```

For more information have a look at the [zshcompsys manpage](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-file_002dsort_002c-completion-style).

---

If you are not yet using the "new" completion system, you can enable it by running `compinstall`, which will allow you to interactively set up the completion system. (It is new in the sense that there is also an old completion system and that there is also the newest completion system. But it was introduced with version 3.1.6 in 1999, so it is already part of any current zsh installation any only needs to be configured)

Alternatively, you can just add the following lines to your `.zshrc` for a minimal/default configuration.

```
# The following lines were added by compinstall
zstyle :compinstall filename "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshrc"

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# End of lines added by compinstall
```

Comment: It _should_ work but it doesn't for me. It's still completes by the default order. Which is neither lexical nor by modification date.

Comment: @user7867665 Hmm… What version of ZSH are you using and do you use any configuration framework (oh-my-zsh, prezto, …) that might interfere?

Comment: zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu), no other configuration. I only ran the first command you suggested on the terminal, not in .zshrc (or in my case it would be .zprofile)

Comment: Do you have the “new” (about 19 year old) completion system loaded? That is, does the command `compinit` appear in your config? Also, `.zprofile` will only loaded for *login shells* (e.g. console or SSH). Within terminal emulators ZSH usually runs as *interactive shell*, so `.zprofile` might not get loaded. (From your question I cannot really tell, which would be the case.)

Comment: I don't think it is loaded. There is no `compinit`. What config? I will try to install it

Comment: You should be able to set up the "new" completion system with the command `compinstall` (it should be part of your zsh installation). It will ask you (quite) a few questions about your preferences and finally write a configuration to your `~/.zshrc`. You can than add/run the command from the answer.